# Apple logic board part number replacement issue

Tags: logicboard, serial-number

I'd like to replace my MBP unibody early 2011 logic board that's broken, so I don't know which is the right choice because two Apple part number seems to be available. The first one is 6616080 and the second one is 6615850 and I'd like to know the difference before. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those are interchangable parts.

Over at [CmdMacParts](https://www.commandmacparts.com/product/logic-board-661-6080), it lists those two part numbers for the same board:

[image]